# Steam authentication with API Gateway and lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, steam

I'm trying to create the authentication of my website using
https://github.com/LeeviHalme/node-steam-openid.

Steam OpenID: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth

I have an API Gateway with these two endpoints:

**/login**

```
// the steamAuth file is the same module as node-steam-openid but for ts
import { SteamAuth } from "../utils/steamAuth";

export const login = async () => {
  const client = new SteamAuth(
      'http://localhost:3000',
      `${process.env.API_URL}/consume`,
      process.env.STEAM_API_KEY,
  );

  try {
    const redirectUrl = await client.getRedirectUrl();
    return {
      statusCode: 302,
      headers: { Location: redirectUrl }
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      message: 'Internal server error'
    };
  }
}
```

**/consume**

```
import { APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';
import { SteamAuth } from "../utils/steamAuth";

export const consume = async (event: APIGatewayEvent) => {
  const client = new SteamAuth(
      'http://localhost:3000',
      `${process.env.API_URL}/consume`,
      process.env.STEAM_API_KEY,
  );

  console.log(event);

  try {
    const user = await client.authenticate(event);
    console.log('success', user);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 302,
    headers: { Location: 'http://localhost:3000/' },
  };
}
```

The thing is I get this error in /consume endpoint

```
error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
    at Object.openid.verifyAssertion (/var/task/node_modules/openid/openid.js:905:28)
    at openid.RelyingParty.verifyAssertion (/var/task/node_modules/openid/openid.js:68:10)
    at /var/task/src/utils/steamAuth.js:60:31
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at SteamAuth.authenticate (/var/task/src/utils/steamAuth.js:59:16)
    at Runtime.consume [as handler] (/var/task/src/lambda/consume.js:9:35)
    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:73:25)
```

I believe this error occurs because the `verifyAssertion` is waiting for an `express request` while it is provided an API Gateway one.

Link to the code with the mentioned function is [here](https://github.com/havard/node-openid/blob/master/http.js)

Should I use another module to do the `authentication` as I don't really want to modify the source code of the module? I didn't find anything at the moment
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using express in lambda. As expected, the openid module used by node-steam-openid is expecting an express request and not a lambda event.

```
import { SteamAuth } from "../utils/steamAuth";

const express = require('express');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');

const app = express();

app.get('/verify', async (req: any, res: any) => {

  const client = new SteamAuth(
    process.env.HOSTNAME,
    `${process.env.API_URL}/verify`,
    process.env.STEAM_API_KEY,
  );
  try {
    const user: any = await client.authenticate(req);

  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
});

module.exports.verify = serverless(app);
```